How to dump and restore a postgres database with data cyphered with pgsodium
I have a database with some data cyphered with pgsodium extension.
Making a dump of the db is working fine. The data are cyphered in the dump, that's what I want.
But when I try to restore the dump the encryption triggers are triggered again. And my restored data is now cyphered twice.
Is there a pgsodium approach to dump and restore db?
I also tried to disable-triggers during restore whitout success.
